# Uber API Request: All Vehicles Currently In Use

Tags: uber-api

I'm making a ride request via the Uber API. I successfully make a request and get a response that it's in the Processing state. I then open my Uber app to watch until it goes into the Accepted state, but it never gets there. After about 15 seconds of processing, it pops up with a weird error message that I've never seen before in the Uber app: "All vehicles are currently in use. Please call (206) 622-6500". I called the phone number just to see, and it's the number for Yellow Cab in Seattle.

I try to make a request using the Uber app as normal, and it works fine.

I'm not making my ride request using the API sandbox; I'm actually trying to request a ride for myself using the limited access request scope for my personal account.

There's not any code to associate with this since I'm making a request successfully. Uber API support has requested that I ask a question on StackOverflow instead of reaching out to them directly.

Comment: Can you add the parameters you are using to request this ride? What product? What location?

Comment: could you share a snippet of your code?